# How to interact between the business logic and a template?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, templates, business-logic

I have the next problem.

I have a page that do:

1. it read the session from the database and all the stuff from the database.
2. "Apply" the logic.
3. and finally the presentation that is a template file (.tpl)

And it works. The template file is a web with a grid and a form where i can CRUDL a database so it can vary according the user that is accessing it.   For example, **if the current user is an administrator then it should display all options, while if it is a limited user then it should hide some fields**.

However, i don't know how to proceed next.  What is the better way to interact between the business logic and the template?.

a) Use a template with logic (*Presentation Logic*). For example, if the users (that is accessing to it) has limited permission then the logic remove the button "save" :

```
 ...
 {if current_user!=limited}
  <input type='button' value='save' />
  ..
 {endif}
 ...
```

- The pro is that it only uses one template.
- The cons is it add logic to the presentation layer.

b) Use different templates files and decide in the business logic which template load.

```
 if ($current_user!="limited") {
    load_template("template_complete.tpl");
 } else {
    load_template("template_limited.tpl");
 }
```

- the pro is the template is more clear (logic-less)
- the cons is it is verbose, it requires different templates.

or exists another solution?.

Comment: A note to someone who may wish to edit tags. The whole topic is about `presentation logic`. It's `business logic` tag that can be removed safely but not presentation one. Thank you.

Comment: Can you find some other questions that could be tagged with it, then?  It's also not clear how it's distinct from templating or from the separation of concerns that MVC implies.

Answer (score 4):

it is totally OK to implement presentation logic in the view. in fact, that is the right place to do it and for the same reason it's also called "presentation layer". You will always reach the point when you need to implement some presentation logic in the view, for example when it comes to iterate an array to display it as a table or when placing error messages below input fields when the input validation failed.

As Michael Rushton already said: you don't want to duplicate code when it can be avoided.

The Model-View-Controller pattern is about dividing the logic in three tiers:

- data representation logic (model)
- business logic (controller)
- presentation logic (view)

It is  *not* about moving *all* logic from the presentation to the controller.

Answer (score 2):

If the templates are completely different then I'd say go for the second example. But if the differences between a limited and a non-limited user are that a few buttons, links, `<div>`s, etc. appear for one but not the other then I say go for the first. You don't want to duplicate your code too much as it makes it more cumbersome to make updates or fix errors.

Although you want to separate logic from presentation as much as you can it is possible to take this too far. There's always going to be some overlap at some point. Providing it's not too complicated there's nothing wrong with having an `<input>` inside a conditional statement.

PHP was built to be used alongside HTML anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than looking at just this example, I'd encourage you to think of what is it you are trying to achieve, create a rule, then work to the rule.

e.g. in the example above, are you trying to stop a user from being presented with certain information? or are you saying that a user has a certain role, and the system should have certain controls to react to certain roles.

Its also a payoff of dev effort now vs maintenance effort later. Maybe try think about what you would do in a perfect world, and work backwards. Maybe you can build a constructor to create the various templates you need, etc.

I don't think there is a right or wrong, just alternatives and different pay offs

Answer (score -1):

Oh. The answer is simple.
Just try to support these different templates for quite a while, diligently repeating all the corrections.

And you'll know the answer.

This is programming, dude.
Programming stands for *avoiding repetitions*.

*Hint:* you can't have your second approach "logic-less" anyway.
There is always a logic. It is called "presentation *logic*" for a reason.

Comment: The concept of those "logic layer" is more holistic rather a real concept. For this matter, the presentation layer is where the designer works and the designer could not have clue about server-side  programming. However, it also means client-side script

Comment: @magallanes in reality designer never works with template. his job is HTML and programmer's job is to make it dynamic, filling with logic.

Comment: well, depend who holds the whip. Im worked with designer that know php and jsp tags while others work only in photoshop (and gives me a psd).

Comment: @magallanes that's 2 kinds of designers. A graphical designer should know nothing of HTML stuff. His job is *imagination* and he produces pictures. While HTML designer is one who CSS (and often JS) pro. Making them both work with templates is very inefficient way. While making PHP programmer responsible for the templates is the right thing. That's just from the experience of the companies I know. There could be exceptions from this setup of course, when followed, it's most efficient: HTML designer makes HTML, PHP programmer makes a template out of it and HTMLer may work with it from now again